# apollo-client, onError, ApolloProvider, client.writeData(localstate)... how to handle authenticating a user when server returns 401

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, apollo, react-apollo

So I have an app using apollo-graphql where certain resolvers are only available to authenticated users and they return a 401 if an unauthenticated user attempts to access them. Nothing groundbreaking there, I know.

However, I am trying to intercept the error, handle it, call a function to log the user out (reset local state session object) then redirect to "/login".

So, here I have the onError: -

```
import { logout } from "_helpers"

const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {    
    ...
    if (networkError && networkError.statusCode === 401) {
        logout()
        history.push('/')
    }
    ...
});
```

Now, I have 2 versions of the logout() function - one where the apollo client is passed in the props and one where I attempted to make it available using ApolloProvider: -

```
import { ApolloConsumer } from "react-apollo"

export const logout = () => {
  return (
    <ApolloConsumer>
    {client => client.writeData({data: {session: {...session, isAuthed: false}}})}
    </ApolloConsumer>
  )
}

export const logout = (client) => {
    client.writeData({data: {session: {...session, isAuthed: false}}})
}
```

The first version - where client is passed in the arguments - has been tried and tested in components where client is already available to the code calling logout(), so client.writeData({data: {session: {...session, isAuthed: false}}}) works fine. However, I wanted to have a version of the function that could be called without having to pass client in the arguments, which is why I have the second version. However, this doesn't work - it doesn't seem to run writeData().

So I would like to know one or both of the following: -

Why doesn't the second version (where ApolloProvider is passing the client) work?

If I wish to simply use a version of logout() where client is passed as a param, is there any way I can make client available inside of my onError() code so it is something like the below?

```
const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
    ...
    if (networkError && networkError.statusCode === 401) {
        logout(client)
        history.push('/')
    }
    ...
});
```

Any help greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer for passing client found here: -

https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link/issues/595